# Runing into a deadlock when using Popen.wait()

Tags: python, large-files, hung

We need to execute a system command using `subprocess.Popen()`.

As the output has a large data, when we tried to use `Popen.wait()` it got stuck.

```
pipe= subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.wait()
```

So, we tried to put `Popen.stdout` in a variable `pstdout`. After which `pstdout` got closed and we are unable to fetch the content in that file.

```
pipe.stdout.closed
pstdout.closed
```

Can anyone help how to avoid that hung or how to reopen `pstdout` ?

Comment: What is the "system command" ? There is very likely a much more idiomatic way of doing what you're after that doesn't involve using subprocesses (which is high on my list of code smells for Python).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting python documentation [popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen) on function `Popen.wait()`:

> Warning This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use `communicate()` to avoid that.

and maybe you are run into deadlock. use communicate instead.

```
p= subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

Comment: Given what OP has told us, this is probably better than the original approach. Although, I'd like to know what the "system command" is, as there is  very likely a cleaner way to do this that doesn't involve using a subprocess at all.

Comment: we have alot of missing details. he didnt say nothing about the command he is runnig, the OS he runs, the demand he wants to fulfil...etc.